# Chrome 34 confirm message PERSISTENT

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, filesystems, persistent

My web site uses PERSISTENT Storage.
http://spinlock.idletime.tk/web/ffmpeg_pnacl/

Chrome 33 confirm about PERSISTENT Storage,only one time.
But Chrome 34 confirm Every time!

Chrome 34 Bug? or My JavaScript is wrong?

```
(function openFS() {
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(1024*1024*100000, function(bytes) {
    window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, bytes, function(fs) {
FS = fs;}, onError);   
});
})();
```

Why???

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My Answer

```
(function openFS() {
    navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.queryUsageAndQuota(function(used, remaining) {
    if(used+remaining < 1)
        navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(1024*1024*100000, function(bytes) {
        webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT,bytes, function(fs) {
            FS = fs;}, onError);});
    else 
            webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT,1024*1024*100000, function(fs) {
            FS = fs;}, onError);
    }, onError );
})();
```